# Why does the か come before です in this question?

Tags: sentence-final-particles

I'm looking through a book of [go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) problems, and ran across the following sentence accompanied by the problem diagram:

> 隅の黒一子が次にアタリですが、ここをどう考えるかです

A rough translation is relatively simple, along the lines of "Black's single stone in the corner is 1 move away from atari (technical term), what do you think about this position?" (By implication: how should black play to survive?)

The go problem is relatively simple. The bit that confused me was the か landing before the です in this question. What does this mean and how does it affect the sentence?

Comment: Note that I did receive an answer from TsuyohiIto in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6192987#6192987) a few days ago.

Answer (score 4):

You know that you can use "koto" or "no" or "mono" to nominalize a proposition, don't you? Well, you can with "ka" as well, when the proposition is a question, direct or indirect.

For example:

1. いつ行くか教えてください. "Tell me when you leave." (Which is nothing else than "Xを教えてください" but where you drop the を because of か.)
2. ポイントは、いつ行くかです。"The point is when you leave." (Which is nothing else than "XはYです".)

Comment: You don't *have* to drop the を because of the か.

Comment: @istrasci: actually, I think I remember being corrected and told to remove the を in similar sentences…

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be the normal use of か inside the sentence, where it then represents "set of answers to that question" (better explained here: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/question, section "「か」 used in relative clauses").

Answer (score 3):

It's very common to say 「[~するかだ](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%82%89%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B&btnG=&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%2a%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%22&oq=%22%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%2a%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%22&gs_l=serp.3...10382.10382.2.10614.1.1.0.0.0.0.193.193.0j1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.r-Nxexa2rc0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=b92cd99b35127bef&biw=1138&bih=579)」. It would be easier for you to get the meaning by inserting 「が重要/問題」 after `か`.

> 隅の黒一子が次にアタリですが、ここをどう考えるかです

隅の黒一子が次にアタリですが、ここをどう考えるか`が重要/問題`です

The translation would be like "Regarding the black piece in the corner which becomes Atari in the next move, it is important how you think here."